# using make_shared with incomplete types

Tags: c++, stl, shared-ptr, incomplete-type, make-shared

I am trying to switch my code to use `make_shared<type>()` but I have a lot of incomplete types (complete at the time of creation) and was wondering if there is anyway make_shared would work with incomplete types or allow me to pass a deleter type.

I looked around and didn't find any posts related to this so either this just works ?? or I am overlooking something basic.

```
#define NEW_PARAMS(Type, ...)   ::std::shared_ptr<Type>(new (Type)(__VA_ARGS__), ::std::default_delete<Type>())
```

Above is the macro I use to create new objects. Would like to convert this to

```
#define NEW_PARAMS(Type, ...)   ::std::make_shared<Type>(__VA_ARGS__, ::std::default_delete<Type>())
```

**EDIT:** Just to clarify I wanted to ask if I could pass a deleter type to the `shared_ptr` created with `make_shared`

Comment: "I wanted to ask if I could pass a deleter type to the shared_ptr created with make_shared" Could you clarify that question by actually asking about *that*, instead of talking mostly about incomplete types which have nothing to do with what you're trying to do? Just restate your question.

Answer (score 3):

No, `make_shared` cannot pass a deleter object to the `shared_ptr` it creates. And generally, you wouldn't need to. Since it uses `new` (placement `new` specifically) to create the pointer, it will need to be deleted by calling the destructor. So there's not much that you could do, since `make_shared` manages the memory directly.

Comment: The type is complete at the time of creation ie when new or make_shared is called.

Comment: @Sharad: Then what error are you getting in the compiler? And where are these uses of `make_shared`?

Comment: Sorry I guess i missed the point in my question. I was wondering if I could pass a deleter to the newly created shared_ptr?